# what am I doing wrong in getting price data from the liq pool?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3, price, sqrtpricelimitx96

```py
import requests
import json
url_v3 = "https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v3"

pools_query_v3 = """
{
    pools(orderBy: txCount, orderDirection: desc) {
        txCount
        id
        sqrtPrice
        token0 {
          decimals
          symbol
        }
        token1 {
          decimals
          symbol
        }
    }
}
"""
payload_v3_pools = json.dumps({
"query": pools_query_v3,
})

headers_pools = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response_v3_pools = requests.request("POST", url_v3, headers=headers_pools, data=payload_v3_pools)
print(response_v3_pools.json())

response_pools = response_v3_pools.json()
data = response_pools['data']
pools = response_pools['data']['pools']
sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

The problem is that some pairs show the correct price but some don't. For example, when I look at the first pair (USDC/WETH), it displays the right price around 2,300.

```py
i = 0
sqrt_price = int(pools[0]['sqrtPrice'])
price = (sqrt_price / 2 **96) ** 2
decimals_diff = int(pools[i]['token1']['decimals']) - int(pools[i]['token0']['decimals'])
# USDC has 6 decimals and WETH has . So, we have to adjust price by 10^18 / 10^6. Then we take the reciprocal of this
# number, because we are interested in USDC/WETH price.
adj_price = 1 / (price / 10 ** decimals_diff)
print(adj_price)
```

But when I look at the second pair ("WETH/USDT"), it displays 2.319e-21 which is obviously wrong.

```py
i = 1
sqrt_price = int(pools[0]['sqrtPrice'])
price = (sqrt_price / 2 **96) ** 2
decimals_diff = int(pools[i]['token1']['decimals']) - int(pools[i]['token0']['decimals'])
# USDC has 6 decimals and WETH has . So, we have to adjust price by 10^18 / 10^6. Then we take the reciprocal of this
# number, because we are interested in USDC/WETH price.
adj_price = 1 / (price / 10 ** decimals_diff)
print(adj_price)
```

Any advice what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? Also, is there a better way to get historical prices from Uniswap v3?

Answer (score 0):

The logic looks correct, you have a typo in the second block of code and the wrong price is used as a result, you probably meant this instead:

```
sqrt_price = int(pools[i]['sqrtPrice'])
```

Regarding alternatives, there are many options. On-chain data will provide the most accurate way how to query prices, however, speed can be an issue. If you're interested in historical on-chain data, you'll need access to an archive node, which should not be a problem, many node providers have this feature.

Comment: Thank you! What a typo :( Do you know any efficient, better, faster etc solution to fetch price from Uniswap v3? Though this works for me, I think there should be a better solution.

Comment: @FadaiMammadov On-chain data does not work for you? There are some other options but I'd start with that